# Allow "equiping" different types of hats at the same time

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash, fun

This is a longshot, and probably not worth it for a feature that's only available for a short period.

However, it would still be cool to allow us to use hats as equipment. The different hat selection gets nicer year after year. It would be nice if I can have the sword, belt, and a hat for example.

It can be something like:

- 1 handheld (ex. guitar, sword, flag)
- 1 headgear (ex. hats, hair, face accessories)
- 1 body gear (ex. bouncer, belt)
- 1 misc - anything that doesn't fit in the previous categories (ex. [truck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3kpS.png), [ladder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mf9v6.png), [stickynote](https://svgur.com/i/SKv.svg))

Comment: This falls under "nice to have, not worth the amount of development time it requires".